# How can I hide Remote Command Center when AVPlayer has finished to play a song?

Tags: ios, xcode, mp3, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I have an app playing mp3 with AVPlayer and I am struggling to hide the Remote Command Center when the track is finished. This is the func to setup my Remote Command Center.

How can I hide it?

func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {

```
    // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
       let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()


       // Add handler for Play Command
       commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.avPlayer?.rate == 0.0 {
               self.togglePlayPause()
               return .success
           }
           return .commandFailed
       }

       // Add handler for Pause Command
       commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.avPlayer?.rate == 1.0 {
               self.togglePlayPause()
               return .success
           }
           return .commandFailed
       }

   let skipForwardCommand = commandCenter.skipForwardCommand
   skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = true
   skipForwardCommand.addTarget(handler: skipForward)
   skipForwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [15]

    let skipBackwardCommand = commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand
    skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    skipBackwardCommand.addTarget(handler: skipForward)
    skipBackwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [15]


    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { [weak self](remoteEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        guard let self = self else {return .commandFailed}
        if let player = self.avPlayer {
           let playerRate = player.rate
           if let event = remoteEvent as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent {
               player.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: event.positionTime, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(1000)), completionHandler: { [weak self](success) in
                   guard let self = self else {return}
                   if success {
                       self.avPlayer?.rate = playerRate
                   }
               })
               return .success
            }
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello from 2022, did you solve it finally?

Answer (score 2):

You have to unregister from remote control events and clear your current playing infos from `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` :

```
UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()        

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [:]
```

You can observe `AvPlayerItem` end with the NotificationCenter observer :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
```

Comment: This is not works for me. MPNowPlayingInfoCenter still visible, but with no title, no image